# can't import permutations after installing anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I am getting ImportError for `from functools import permutations`, but it was working before. I am on windows 7 and the only major change I see is installing 
Anaconda now. I had python 2.7.10 when it was working, and anaconda 2.7.9...I tried uninstalling the regular python and running python in the Anaconda prompt, and still the same error. How can I fix this and still keep Anaconda? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing `permutations` in the documentation for `functools`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

I am, however, seeing it in `itertools`, perhaps you misspelt?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html